# Laravel method save(), data inserted twice

Tags: sql, laravel, duplicates

I have a condition to insert/save a new referral record to DB. but from thousand of records, 3 duplicate records happened in the system this week. I know I don't have a unique id from the beginning. but is there any way to prevent it from happening in the current system? coz this only happened this week. Does anyone know the root cause of why it happened? I try some conditions such as double click, double click with a slow connection, disabling the network when submitting, then enabling and submitting again. But only 1 record is stored in DB.

**Controller**

```
$referral = new Referral;
$referral->fullname = $request->fullname;
$referral->mobile_phone = $request->phone;
$referral->id_registration = $id_reg;
//$referral etc...
$referral->save();

try {
    Mail::send('mail.user.referral_creation', compact('email', 'fullname', 'user'),
        function ($message) use ($template, $email, $fullname, $main_sender_email, $main_sender_name) {
            $message->from($main_sender_email, $main_sender_name);
            $message->subject($template->greeting);
            $message->to($email, $fullname);
        });
    
    return redirect('/')->with(['success' => 'success']);
} catch (\Swift_TransportException $e) {
    \Log::error($e);
    
    return redirect('/')->with(['error' => 'error']);
}
```

the timestamp(created_at) show almost the same time, dif in second

Record 1  2023-08-10 17:22:01

Record 1 2023-08-10 17:22:02

Record 2 2023-08-14 7:30:36

Record 2 2023-08-14 7:30:36

Record 3 2023-08-14 17:26:09

Record 3 2023-08-14 17:26:10

**Referral model**

```
class Referral extends Model implements Auditable{
use \OwenIt\Auditing\Auditable;
protected $table = 'referrals';
protected $fillable = ['fullname', 'mobile_phone','email',...]
                ];
use SoftDeletes;
protected $guarded = ["id"]; 
protected $dates   = ['deleted_at'];
public $timestamps = true;  }
```

Comment: the code itself doesn't have any problem, can you share your code more ? like, is it inside loop ? or how you handle the request overall ?

Comment: only that, its register page with basic form, in controller there is save function, then send email function, i check on log, no error related send email

Comment: can i see your ```Referral``` model ?

Comment: I still don't see anything wrong with your code. So this problem must've come from the frontend. Can I know what route that the form resides on ? Also you can check your network tab and see if it's really get submitted twice on the frontend

Comment: Add a unique constraint to 'email' and/or 'mobile_phone', etc.

Comment: Are you using version control like git? Can you checkout to previous version where it does not replicate? Check the last known git commit where replicate happened.

Comment: no migration/updated code in production right now, just get the report if admin cant assign the application. when i check, there are 3 cases whose duplicate. i also wondering what the root cause. coz i try some scenario by user behaviour like double click, or disable internet when submit etc, i also try with dif browser, but it only save 1 time.